# It is said that Kali was present in Satyug as Gandharva and in Dwapar as dice, the biggest sinner lived through it all

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, kali-yuga, dwapara-yuga

Kali did many wrong things in Dwapar Yug and in Satyug and yet he is spared.

The main of starting another yug to start over and eradicate all that is wrong in current yug.

Its almost like he is a Chiranjivi without any vardan. Why is such a sinner not killed yet and was allowed to live through these Yugas

Why was he not killed!

Comment: There were attempts to kill him, but kali can take any form and can reside within others rather he is in everyone so he cant be killed. Another way to answer this question would be, because it was predestined that kali will be killed in kali yuga!